# Can't get pagination to fetch all reviews?

Tags: python, json, pagination

I'm using python3 and JSON to use pagination. Everything has worked up until now, I was able to use pagination to fetch all business however the same is not working to fetch all the reviews of a single business.

This is the code I used to fetch all businesses that worked:

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses", methods = ["GET"])
def show_all_businesses():
    page_num, page_size = 1, 10
    if request.args.get("pn"):
        page_num = int(request.args.get("pn"))
    if request.args.get("ps"):
        page_size = int(request.args.get("ps"))
    page_start = (page_size * (page_num - 1))
    businesses_list = [{k : v} for k, v in businesses.items()]
    data_to_return = businesses_list[page_start:page_start + page_size]
    return make_response(jsonify(data_to_return), 200)
```

This is the code I am using to fetch all reviews, if there are no current reviews the program is returning an empty list however when I add a review I am receiving an error:

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses/<string:b_id>/reviews", methods = ["GET"])
def fetch_all_reviews(b_id):
    page_num, page_size = 1, 10
    if request.args.get("pn"):
        page_num = int(request.args.get("pn"))
    if request.args.get("ps"):
        page_size = int(request.args.get("ps"))
    page_start = (page_size * (page_num - 1))
    reviews_list = [{k, v} for k, v in businesses[b_id]["reviews"].items()]
    data_to_return = reviews_list[page_start:page_start + page_size]
    return make_response(jsonify(data_to_return), 200)
```

I have tried accessing the reviews through indexing that has worked right up until I have introduced pagination to them. I am expecting the program to return all reviews when it is working properly as it was before pagination was introduced to it.

Comment: What is your issue? What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: I'm receiving this error in Postman after I POST a review then use the GET method to retrieve the reviews of that particular business: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'